# Post to Get method Conversion Vulnerability in ASP.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can an Asp.Net web application be prevented from accepting Post to Get method conversion. More precisely, how can 'GET' requests be rejected where a 'POST' data is expected.
I will greatly appreciate clarification on how this VULNERABILITY occurs and how it can be prevented.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you can check for a POST by doing Page.IsPostBack in web forms:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

If you're talking MVC, you generally just set the [HttpPost] attribute: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute.aspx